# Replace all exceptions from a class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, exception, objectdisposedexception

Is there a way in C# to replace all the `ObjectDisposedException` thrown by an instance of a `NetworkStresm` with `MyException`?

The purpose of this is that I want to read and write the stream while other threads may dispose it. And that's just fine - when the stream is disposed the exception is thrown and I handle it and it's part of the normal flow of the program (since the client may just disconnect). As opposed to other `ObjectDisposedException` of other objects that are really an error, a bug in my code.

So if I could make the stream throw `MyException` instead of the regular `ObjectDisposedException`, I could treat it differently.

Any other suggestions to accomplish this purpose  are good as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a better solution would be not to share the object between threads, ensure each thread has it's own instance of the `IDisposable` object and have each thread control when its own instance is disposed. Then you know when you get a `ObjectDisposedException` it is always a bug

Comment: Exceptions should never be part of the "normal flow" of a program, exceptions happen because something exceptional took place, don't use exceptions for control flow, it will lead to horrible headaches later.

Comment: @Ron Beyer If the client suddenly closes the stream it is both exceptional (I did not control it and I wish it didn't happen) and normal (it's not a bug in my code and I should consider it can happen). For real exceptional exceptions I close everything, restart and log the whole trace. For normal exceptions I just log a nice little warning

Comment: @Ben Robinson It still means that when the client disconnects and I write the stream (for example) an exception will be thrown. And then either I would have to try catch every read/write or again try catch in the main function and not know whether the exception is because the client has disconnected

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want that to happen you are going to have to catch `ObjectDisposedException` and rethrow `MyException`.

A better alternative (if you control the code you are calling) is to have the code on the other side check if it is already disposed and not throw `ObjectDisposedException`, but just return without doing anything.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to try catch every time I read or write. That's just code duplication

Comment: And what do you mean by "the code on the other side"? The client's code? I don't have it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to do this, but you might be able to achieve similar behavior by using the `ObjectName` property of the `ObjectDisposedException` to handle all of the exceptions thrown by a `NetworkStream` and rethrow the rest.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it but the problem is, what if later I will create another stream that should have the regular behavior? Also this feels very hacky